# Connect SQL Server 2008 r2 through Internet

Tags: sql-server-2008, networking, vb.net-2010

I have a VB.NET application that can connect to the SQL Server through LAN base, but how can I connect to it through internet, the application need to use outside, I know i need to use the public IP instead of using the IP address of the server but my public IP address that I've set in connection string can't connect to the server, Here's my connection string

`Dim connstr$ = "Server=xxx.xx.xx.xxx\SQLEXPRESS,xxxx;Initial Catalog=sample_db;Integrated Security=True
Public conn As New SqlConnection(connstr)`

I've try also to set the port and change the firewall restriction,enabled the TCP etc. and search a lot here but still doesn't work

Here's our network setup

PC-->router-->internet modem

Comment: From an external computer (one not on the LAN), you can test that you can connect on the port/IP address with this command: `TELNET <IP ADDRESS> <Port>`. You need to first verify if that works. If it _does_ work, try and find a connection string that uses ip address/port rather than instance name (SQLEXPRESS). If Telnet _doesn't_ work, you need to troubleshoot your firewall to allows connections through on the port. You also need to be certain what port the SQL Server is running on. There are guides to all of these different pieces all over the internet.

Comment: so I need to connect the internet modem directly to the PC?

Comment: It sounds like your main problem is setting up a test device that is outside your LAN. If you have another PC and a phone you could tether the PC to the phone (not your LAN) and get to the internet that way. There are probably software solutions for this too.

Comment: Although it's possibly not as important in this case, can you expand on 'doesn't work'. These are the two most frustrating words that are ever written in a help forum.

Comment: anyway.. what do you see if you try the telnet I mentioned above? What happens if you type `tracert <your IP address>`

Comment: When I try the TELNET command it shown a message "< was unexpected at this time" and when I try the tracert command it shown a message,

"over maximum of 30 hops: 1 1ms 1ms 1ms [name of PC] [xxx.xxx.xx.xxx]",Ive tried the tracert command on the same LAN.  yup my main problem is connecting the sql server from our home to other place.

Comment: an example would be `TELNET 100.1.1.1 73`. 73 is the port you have natted through your router to your SQL Servers port. I'm guessing if you are not familiar with TELNET, you probably are not familiar with NATing?

Comment: Thank you for your time sir, I really appreciate your help. Yes, you're right i'm not familiar in NAT. can you guide me step by step on how I can make it from NATing until I connect it to sql please?

Comment: I will give you some basic steps. Complete each of these by researching on Google. If you have issues, post a specific question: 1) Find the port that SQL Server is running on. 2) Configure your network router to allow access to that port by using NAT. 3) Connect using a connection string that specifies the port, not the instance.  I can't help you any further, you'll need to do some research and post any specific problems you have.

Answer (score 0):

1433 is the default sql server communication port. Port 1433 should be forwarded to the local IP address  where your sql server runs.

1) Make sure that port 1433 is the valid communication port for sql server. You can check it from sql server configuration tools. Use actual port number rather than 1443 if it was changed by someone.

2) Find NAT (Network address translation) menu in your modem or router administration panel.

3) Forward port 1433 to your server's local IP address

4) Restart device

As a note that, your modem does not require a static IP. Your device most probably might have a new IP address after every restart. But it would be valid until you restart it once more. You can use this IP address in order to access your database remotely. It would be better but you don't have to get a static IP address.

UPDATE: You should also be sure that, port is not blocked by a program on the server such as a virus or security program.

Good luck

Comment: If he is indeed connecting to SQLEXPRESS then 1433 will not be the default port.

Comment: Good Day! thanks for the reply but How can I forward the port 1433 to my local IP address?should I change all the setting of IP address and port in TCP/IP from IP1 to IP10? sorry for my question, I'm really new in using SQL server. 

I've seen the NAT menu in our router but its different from other router, we use a QNO router here, it is a  multiwan router so i thinks it has also a effect on it.

Comment: No you've got it backwards. First work out what port your SQL Server is running on. Do a google search. Then pick an arbitrary port (say 60000) and forward that port in the Internet side to the SQL Server port on your 'local' side. If you haven't done that yet, you will not be able to connect. Get that working first.

Comment: It is hard to say how to configure your router. You can simply search documentation on your router vendor's support page or you can consult your network administrator (if exist). I assumed that your app runs on your LAN without any problem. It means that your connection string and sql server well confiugured. I can send additional suggestions if you post information about your network topology.

Answer (score 0):

Google "port forwarding", which is also called Network address translation or "NAT".
The other answers are perfect but searching for the term on google should get you an idea on what it is, and how to go about it. Add your router name to the search for exact steps.
In short forward the port that SQL Server is listening on, from the router to the server machine. You will need to do some configuration on the router for that by opening the admin page. For how and details, Google "port forwarding"